# How to set focus from one UIButton to Another UIButton in UIToolbar Done Button

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am working with iPhone Application with creating single object multiple dynamic button in `UITableView`. And when user will press button every time `UIDatePicker` will open to select date. So Is is possible to move focus from one `UIButton` to another `UIButton` after date selection. I am explaining you in detail as follows:

I have create `UITableView` with single object Multiple `Custom UIButtons`. When user will click on all this button the `UIDatePicker` will show with `Next` and `Cancel` UIToolBar. When user select date from datePicker and press Next button i want focus or select for the next `UIButton` to give facility to select date from datePicker for another button. Like flow without removing view for transaction.

So is it possible to Focus on another button after pressing `Next` button to another button.I googled around but could not find any solution for this.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can.. Perform following steps:

1. Set Different style for your buttons for Highlighted state.
2. Give a unique tag for each Button.
3. Lets say you have 5 buttons with tags 0 to 4. In your TouchUpInsideEvent write this,

   - (IBAction)onButtonClick:(UIButton *)sender 
     {
     for(UIButton * btn in myButtons)//Mybuttons is outletCollection of buttons
     {
       if (btn.tag == sender.tag + 1)
       {
            [btn setHighlighted:YES];
             break;
        }
     }
     }

If it does not work with Highlighted state, you can try with Selected state. (I think it will work with selected state only .. :))

Comment: Thanks for your reply i will try it and let you know about changes.